# Office Add-In for Excel falsely acts on every open workbook

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013, add-in

Using Excel-2010, VS-2013,

I created an 'Office Add-In' that adds functionality to Excel. (The functionality, for example involves new Shortcut-Actions that color certain Excel-Cells.)

[image]

Everything is working perfectly - except that the functionality added is carried out on all open Excel-workbooks at once! This is not the intention. The intention is that this Add-In functionality only performs on the one Excel-workbook the user currently works with.

Is there any idea on how to achieve this ? (i.e. Add-In functionality limited to only the Excel-workbook currently worked at - not the other open ones too)

Comment: I am not sure how you were able to achieve this (show your code or way to reproduce the issue), but you can refer to the currently active Workbook with something like `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: I used `private delegate IntPtr HookProcedure(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    private static HookProcedure procedure = HookCallback;` And therefore all my shortcuts (from other Excels or even other Windows applications) provoke an event. The question is, how can I find out within an Excel-AddIn which keyboard-shortcut was pressed and also which Excel-Workbook it came from. Your above answer (i.e. `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook`) fires inside any open Excel-Workbooks and therefore is not enough to distinguish where exactly the shortcut came from. Any ideas ?

Comment: global hook that handles all events seems like a bad idea. There are many Workbook properties that can be used to identify it: `.Name`, `.Names`, `.CodeName`, `.VBProject`, `.BuiltinDocumentProperties`, `.CustomDocumentProperties`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a  look at those!