# How to detect in which Excel-workbook was clicked ?

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013, office-addins

Using Excel-2010, Visual-Studio-2013 Professional,

I am trying to find out programatically, in which Excel-Workbook a mouse-click occurrs (or keyboard-shortcut occurs would also be acceptable)? There are several ideas I persuaded, but all of them show the same issue: The Excel-AddIn used does get executed for all open Excel-Workbooks and messes up the needed information in a sense that it does give me the wrong origin of the mouse-click (or keyboard-shortcut click). It does not tell me the desired origin-window but tells me that the click occurred from a window that is not active by all means! I really don't know why the below code-snippets return arbitrary workbook-origins (but never the one I needed, which is the one window I click inside!)...

**What is the best way to tell from which window a mouse-click (or keyboard-shortcut) occurrs having several Excel-Workbooks open working with the same Excel-AddIn code ???**

Here is what I tried so far:

A) As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827715/office-add-in-for-excel-falsely-acts-on-every-open-workbook), a global keyboard-hook was not the solution.

B) GetActiveWindow()

```
const int nChars = 256;
IntPtr handle1 = GetActiveWindow();
StringBuilder Buff1 = new StringBuilder(nChars);
if (GetWindowText(handle1, Buff1, nChars) > 0) {
    MessageBox.Show(Buff1.ToString());
}
```

C) GetForegroundWindow()

```
const int nChars = 256;
IntPtr handle2 = GetForegroundWindow();
StringBuilder Buff2 = new StringBuilder(nChars);
if (GetWindowText(handle2, Buff2, nChars) > 0) {
    MessageBox.Show(Buff2.ToString());
}
```

D) ApplicationIsActivated()

```
public static bool ApplicationIsActivated()
{
    var activatedHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
    if (activatedHandle == IntPtr.Zero) {
        return false;       // No window is currently activated
    }

    var procId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
    int activeProcId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(activatedHandle, out activeProcId);

    MessageBox.Show(activeProcId.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(procId.ToString());
    return activeProcId == procId;
}
```

Needed imports for the above code-snippets:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out int processId);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetFocus();
```

Any idea appreciated!